# Partition in quick sort logical error

Tags: c++, sorting, logic, quicksort

```
int partition(int A[], int low, int high){
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    int pivot = A[mid];
    while(low <= high) {
        while(low <= high && A[high] >= pivot) {
            high--;
        }
        while (low <= high && A[low] <= pivot) {
            low ++;
        }
        if(low <= high) {
            int tmp = A[low];
            A[low] = A[high]; 
            A[high] = tmp;
            high--;
           low++;
        }
    }
    return mid;
}

void quickSort(int A[], int low, int high) {
    if (low >= high) {
      return;
    }
    int ppos = partition(A, low, high);//does the swapping and returns the pivot
    quickSort(A, low, ppos-1);
    quickSort(A, ppos+1, high);
}
```

This is my quicksort function with a partition to do the swapping and return the pivot so that quicksort recalls itself with a different midpoint. I'm not too familiar with quicksort but this is what i came up with.

The problem is that it compiles fine but when it runs it always crashes. Is there a logical flaw with my functions? Any advice on how to fix my functions so that it'll do quicksort on a random array?

-edit-
fixed the crashing error, but partition won't do the sorting properly, any suggestions to change the function so that it does quicksort on the array?

Comment: Test the `partition` function independently of `quickSort` and make sure it works. If not, use a debugger for step-by-step debugging.

Comment: A debugger is a tool you 100% need to use for anything other than a trivial project. Please learn the one provided with your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partition function is incorrect. There are two primary methods for partitioning a sequence during quicksort: the *squeeze* and the *sweep*. The former of these is the one you're attempting and has a high likelihood of fewer swaps than the latter method at the price of a more complicated algorithm.

---

**The Sweep**

I'll show you what the simpler *sweep* method looks like first, as it is honestly the simplest to understand. In general, the algorithm does the following:

1. Exit early if the sequence length is less than two. There is nothing to partition for a sequence of length-one.
2. Choose a pivot value in the sequence. Choosing a pivot value that reduces the chances of a O(N^2) degenerate condition is the holy-grail of quicksort partitioning, and I'll not cover it here, but there are *plenty* of writs on the subject available online.
3. Swap the pivot value with the last value in the sequence.
4. Walk the sequence with two index values; the reader index and the writer index. as you march up the sequence any reader-indexed value that is "less than" the pivot value is swapped into the lower sequence at the writer-index, and the writer index is incremented.
5. When finished, the writer index is the point where the pivot value is swapped into final position and the partition is complete. The resulting partition point returned is the writer index position.

This algorithm is actually *easier* to understand with code:

```
size_t partition(int A[], size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2) // 1.
        return 0;

    std::iter_swap(A+len/2, A+len-1); // 2. 3.
    size_t pvt = 0;

    for (size_t i=0; i<len-1; ++i) // 4.
    {
        if (A[i] < A[len-1])
            std::iter_swap(A + pvt++, A+i);
    }
    std::iter_swap(A + pvt, A+len-1); // 5.

    return pvt;
}
```

Note it is entirely conceivable values *larger* than the pivot value may well be swapped *multiple* times as the lower partition is filled during the march. Eventually it all settles out, but these additional swaps are ideally avoided. That is the purpose of the *squeeze* method, shown next.

---

**The Squeeze**

While the *sweep* has its advantages (most notable being simplicity), minimizing swaps is not among them. Ideally you only perform a swap when you have determined *two* values are out of place on opposite sides of the eventual landing home of the pivot value. To do this requires you perform a low-to-high sweep *simultaneously* with a high-to-low sweep, and as soon as each finds an element in the incorrect location, swap *those*. Eventually the low index and high index meet, and upon doing so you've found the pivot final resting place.

```
size_t partition(int A[], size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return 0;

    std::iter_swap(A + len/2, A+len-1);
    size_t low = 0, high = len;

    while (1)
    {
        while (low < high && (A[low] < A[len-1]))
            ++low;

        if (low == high--)
            break;

        while (low < high && !(A[high] < A[len-1]))
            --high;

        if (low == high)
            break;

        std::iter_swap(A+low++, A+high);
    }
    std::iter_swap(A+low, A+len-1);

    return low;
}
```

There a several things going on here that may seem odd. Note the boolean logic for the *second* inner-while loop that reduces `high`. I could have written `(A[high] >= A[len-1])` but I wanted to drive home a common mistake. It is ***critical*** the condition which reduces `high` be logically *inverse* to that which promotes `low`. If `low` is promoted because its element is strictly less than the pivot value as we have it here, then `high` can only be reduced if its element is  **not** (strictly less than the pivot value). The is no doubt we have it right when shown as coded above, and I simply cannot do justice to the number of times that specific requirement is glossed over and resulted in mysteriously broken partitioning algorithms.

---

**Sample partitions with QuickSort**

Either of the above will work. A few slight modifications to the functions to produce output when a swap happens and sorting a randomly shuffled array of values demonstrates the swap-count reduction. The following implements both algorithms in two partition functions, appropriately labeled `sweep` and `squeeze`. They are both turned loose on identical random sequences, then again on fully-sorted sequences to demonstrate the swap-count differences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>

size_t sweep(int A[], size_t len)
{
    if (len < 2)
        return 0;

    std::iter_swap(A+len/2, A+len-1);
    size_t pvt = 0;

    for (size_t i=0; i<len-1; ++i)
    {
        if (A[i] < A[len-1])
        {
            std::cout << "swap: " << A[pvt] << ',' << A[i] << '\n';
            std::iter_swap(A + pvt++, A+i);
        }
    }
    std::iter_swap(A + pvt, A+len-1);

    return pvt;
}

size_t squeeze(int A[], size_t len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
        return 0;

    std::iter_swap(A + len/2, A+len-1);
    size_t low = 0, high = len;

    while (1)
    {
        while (low < high && A[low] < A[len-1])
            ++low;

        if (low == high--)
            break;

        while (low < high && !(A[high] < A[len-1]))
            --high;

        if (low == high)
            break;

        std::cout << "swap: " << A[low] << ',' << A[high] << '\n';
        std::iter_swap(A+low++, A+high);
    }
    std::iter_swap(A+low, A+len-1);

    return low;
}

void quicksort(int A[], size_t len, size_t (*part)(int[], size_t))
{
    if (len < 2)
        return;

    size_t pvt = part(A, len);
    quicksort(A, pvt++, part);
    quicksort(A+pvt, len-pvt, part);
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());

    int ar[31] = {0}, ar2[31];
    std::iota(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), 1);
    std::shuffle(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), rng);
    std::copy(std::begin(ar), std::end(ar), std::begin(ar2));

    for (auto x : ar)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Sweep Algorithm\n";
    quicksort(ar, sizeof(ar)/sizeof(*ar), sweep);

    for (auto x : ar)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Squeeze Algorithm\n";
    quicksort(ar2, sizeof(ar2)/sizeof(*ar2), squeeze);

    for (auto x : ar2)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Sweep Algorithm (sorted)\n";
    quicksort(ar, sizeof(ar)/sizeof(*ar), sweep);

    for (auto x : ar)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Squeeze Algorithm (sorted)\n";
    quicksort(ar2, sizeof(ar2)/sizeof(*ar2), squeeze);

    for (auto x : ar2)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output** (random)

```
8 28 21 26 10 12 17 1 11 20 30 3 18 5 24 15 9 6 13 27 31 4 16 7 19 22 14 25 29 2 23 
Sweep Algorithm
swap: 8,8
swap: 28,10
swap: 21,12
swap: 26,1
swap: 28,11
swap: 21,3
swap: 17,5
swap: 26,9
swap: 28,6
swap: 20,13
swap: 30,4
swap: 21,7
swap: 18,14
swap: 17,2
swap: 8,8
swap: 10,1
swap: 12,3
swap: 10,5
swap: 11,2
swap: 12,6
swap: 10,4
swap: 11,7
swap: 8,1
swap: 3,3
swap: 5,5
swap: 7,4
swap: 3,3
swap: 4,4
swap: 3,3
swap: 7,7
swap: 13,10
swap: 12,12
swap: 13,13
swap: 12,12
swap: 23,20
swap: 26,16
swap: 28,19
swap: 23,18
swap: 27,17
swap: 20,16
swap: 20,17
swap: 20,18
swap: 16,16
swap: 30,22
swap: 24,24
swap: 30,26
swap: 31,28
swap: 30,27
swap: 26,26
swap: 27,27
swap: 26,26
swap: 30,30
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
Squeeze Algorithm
swap: 28,2
swap: 21,14
swap: 26,7
swap: 17,4
swap: 20,13
swap: 30,6
swap: 18,9
swap: 14,3
swap: 7,4
swap: 14,9
swap: 12,6
swap: 30,25
swap: 27,21
swap: 31,22
swap: 23,16
swap: 25,17
swap: 30,28
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
Sweep Algorithm (sorted)
swap: 1,1
swap: 2,2
swap: 3,3
swap: 4,4
swap: 5,5
swap: 6,6
swap: 7,7
swap: 8,8
swap: 9,9
swap: 10,10
swap: 11,11
swap: 12,12
swap: 13,13
swap: 14,14
swap: 15,15
swap: 1,1
swap: 2,2
swap: 3,3
swap: 4,4
swap: 5,5
swap: 6,6
swap: 7,7
swap: 1,1
swap: 2,2
swap: 3,3
swap: 1,1
swap: 5,5
swap: 9,9
swap: 10,10
swap: 11,11
swap: 9,9
swap: 13,13
swap: 17,17
swap: 18,18
swap: 19,19
swap: 20,20
swap: 21,21
swap: 22,22
swap: 23,23
swap: 17,17
swap: 18,18
swap: 19,19
swap: 17,17
swap: 21,21
swap: 25,25
swap: 26,26
swap: 27,27
swap: 25,25
swap: 29,29
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
Squeeze Algorithm (sorted)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're returning the value of the pivot instead of its position in the partition function.

Comment: edited to return the "mid" instead but something seems wrong with the partition it's not sorting all of the numbers correctly. Any logical tips to help the partition function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is is an implementation using a partition index:

```
void swap(int A[], int i1, int i2){
    int temp=A[i1];
    A[i1]=A[i2];
    A[i2]=temp;
}

int partition(int A[], int low, int high){
    int partitionIndex, i, pivot;

    pivot = A[high];
    partitionIndex=low;

    for(i=low; i < high; i++){
        if(A[i]<=pivot){
            swap(A,i,partitionIndex);
            partitionIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(A,high,partitionIndex);
    return partitionIndex;
}

void quickSort(int A[], int low, int high) {
    if (low < high){
        int ppos = partition(A, low, high);//does the swapping and returns the pivot
        quickSort(A, low, ppos-1);
        quickSort(A, ppos+1, high);
    }
}
```

I could not figure out what was wrong with your code. In the middle of debugging i noticed that you edited the code in the question. Hope the above code helps you in root causing the issue.

Comment: it was a small edit because i return the value of the pivot instead of the pivot spot itself.

Comment: why does the pivot start @ high? wouldn't we want it to start off in the middle?

Comment: The beauty of quick sort is that it will sort your values regardless of how you judge to get a pivot.